# What is the best way to import a Maya model to three.js scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, maya

I have a model that was made using Maya. I'm trying to import the model to WebGL.  I tried ColladaLoader in `three.js` and the gradient texture doesn't show.
The ColladaLoader showed the most accurate render of the model. The `three.js` exporter to JSON did not work with my version of Maya. What can I do to make the gradient show in WebGL?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing you can do to properly import textures "as this" from COLLADA, or any other exchange format, to or from WebGL, OpenGL, Maya, Blender, XSI, 3DsMAX, etc. There is no "good easy solution" for that.

Textures are usualy references to external files, they are not embeded in the exported format (this is true for almost all 3D format, at least all those I know). Sometimes, external files are copied in the same location than the exported 3D files, to help, in the hypothetical case the importer know what to do with these external references (this is rarely the case).

In adition, in your case, if I well understand, this is a "Gradient", so, a procedural texture, so there even no existing external file to copy... So, Maya is supposed to sample you procedural texture into a bitmap file, then copy it with the DAE file... This is as far as i know far beyond what Maya accept to do for you natively.

So, the good answer is unfortunately: You have to do the job yourself. Exporting file, making the texture, copy the texture in the right place, rebuild the material within the WebGL context, relink the texture, etc...

Comment: How can a put a mesh over a collada file in three.js? It doesn't seem that I can.

Comment: Can I add texture to a collada file in three.js?

Comment: I don't think so. However, i don't know three.js enough (which is an API) to be able to tell you the exact steps, but this is something like that: 1) Import COLLADA in Three.js 2) In Three.js load your texture 3) Locate the imported COLLADA mesh and the right material 4) Link your loaded texture to the right materia. So to say : you have to recompose your material yourself once imported in Three.js

Comment: Maya can obviously take that procedureal texture and render it into a file if you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

The **Maya-to-Three.js exporter** is **no longer supported**. I also don't recommend using COLLADA since it is not optimized for the web. Instead, you might try some third-party glTF 2.0 plugin to export your 3D assets to WebGL, such as **Verge3D** etc.